Can't scroll up/left on HTML/CSS website when zoomed in
I'm making a little portfolio website for myself. I want everything to be static, so zooming in doesn't affect the formatting of the containers, which I have managed to do. However, when I zoom in, I can't navigate throughout the page by scrolling. Well, I can scroll down and to the right, but I can't scroll up and down.
100% scaling
250% scaling
I tried using transform-origin: top left; because I saw it in another thread, but it didn't quite work.
Also tried adding overflow-y: scroll/auto; to html/body/scale-container.


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'CascadiaMonoNF', sans-serif;
  background-color: #221a2e;
  color: #EACDC2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.scale-container {
  transform: scale(1.75) translateX(30px);
  transform-origin: center;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: static;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #221a2e;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.code-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.line-numbers {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #2C1F35;
  color: #6C4F6D;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border-right: 1px solid #3A2B3A;
}

.line-number {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.code-content {
  padding-left: 9.99px;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.content-container {
  background-color: #291e38;
  max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-left: -10.5px;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #C66976;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.social-icons a {
  color: #EACDC2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.social-icons a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #C66976;
}

.intro-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.intro-list li {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #EACDC2;
}

section {
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #9266BD;
}

.projects h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

.projects .project-link {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #EACDC2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.projects .project-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #C66976;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #EACDC2;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.language-section {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.language-section h4 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #B17490;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>shrijan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="assets/icons/s.png" type="image/png">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scale-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="code-container">
        <div class="line-numbers">
          <div class="line-number">1</div>
          <div class="line-number">2</div>
          <div class="line-number">3</div>
          <div class="line-number">4</div>
          <div class="line-number">5</div>
          <div class="line-number">6</div>
          <div class="line-number">7</div>
          <div class="line-number">8</div>
          <div class="line-number">9</div>
          <div class="line-number">10</div>
          <div class="line-number">11</div>
          <div class="line-number">12</div>
          <div class="line-number">13</div>
          <div class="line-number">14</div>
          <div class="line-number">15</div>
          <div class="line-number">16</div>
          <div class="line-number">17</div>
        </div>
        <div class="code-content">
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="header-container">
              <h1>shrijan</h1>
              <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">twitter</a>
                <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank">linkedin</a>
                <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">github</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="intro-list">
              <li>21 years old software developer</li>
              <li>east coast based</li>
              <li>interest in SWE, systems design, ML/AI</li>
            </ul>

            <section class="projects">
              <h3>projects</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">linux simulator</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">bloons in the terminal</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">text file data aggregator</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">queue buster (wip)</a></li>
              </ul>
            </section>

            <section class="languages">
              <h3>languages</h3>
              <div class="language-section">
                <h4>proficient</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>c++/c</li>
                  <li>java & javascript</li>
                  <li>python</li>
                </ul>
                <h4>learning</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>zig</li>
                  <li>rust</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




You can try replacing the relevant css classes with the following code:


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
  font-family: 'CascadiaMonoNF', sans-serif;
  background-color: #221a2e;
  color: #EACDC2;
  display: flex;
}

.scale-container {
  transform: none;
  transform-origin: center;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: static;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #221a2e;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.code-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.line-numbers {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #2C1F35;
  color: #6C4F6D;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border-right: 1px solid #3A2B3A;
}

.line-number {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.code-content {
  padding-left: 9.99px;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.content-container {
  background-color: #291e38;
  margin-left: -10.5px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #C66976;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.social-icons a {
  color: #EACDC2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.social-icons a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #C66976;
}

.intro-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.intro-list li {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #EACDC2;
}

section {
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #9266BD;
}

.projects h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

.projects .project-link {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #EACDC2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>shrijan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="assets/icons/s.png" type="image/png">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scale-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="code-container">
        <div class="line-numbers">
          <div class="line-number">1</div>
          <div class="line-number">2</div>
          <div class="line-number">3</div>
          <div class="line-number">4</div>
          <div class="line-number">5</div>
          <div class="line-number">6</div>
          <div class="line-number">7</div>
          <div class="line-number">8</div>
          <div class="line-number">9</div>
          <div class="line-number">10</div>
          <div class="line-number">11</div>
          <div class="line-number">12</div>
          <div class="line-number">13</div>
          <div class="line-number">14</div>
          <div class="line-number">15</div>
          <div class="line-number">16</div>
          <div class="line-number">17</div>
        </div>
        <div class="code-content">
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="header-container">
              <h1>shrijan</h1>
              <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">twitter</a>
                <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank">linkedin</a>
                <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">github</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="intro-list">
              <li>21 years old software developer</li>
              <li>east coast based</li>
              <li>interest in SWE, systems design, ML/AI</li>
            </ul>

            <section class="projects">
              <h3>projects</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">linux simulator</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">bloons in the terminal</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">text file data aggregator</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="project-link">queue buster (wip)</a></li>
              </ul>
            </section>

            <section class="languages">
              <h3>languages</h3>
              <div class="language-section">
                <h4>proficient</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>c++/c</li>
                  <li>java & javascript</li>
                  <li>python</li>
                </ul>
                <h4>learning</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>zig</li>
                  <li>rust</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Perhaps I'm missing the point of the question, but this seems to drastically change the appearance in the default state, which doesn't seem like what the asker wanted?

Can you please describe what you are referring to?

If you run the both snippets (and use the "Full page" option so it's easier to see), the alignment of both the container and the content seem to have changed. I think the asker was just trying to get the page to scroll when the transform caused the container to overflow the page.
